# Batch - Returning full path from a dir /b

Tags: batch-file

I am traversing folders on a drive, collecting file names with specific extensions, and building a string which is later used in a command line switch. When I find a qualifying file I need to know its full path as this is what is required by the command line. I currently use "%~dp0%%a\%%b" to build the full path, but I can see that may have limitations later on when the batch becomes more complex (e.g. it digs deeper into sub folders). I am hoping there is a way to replace "%~dp0%%a\%%b" with the path to the located file. Thank you:

```
@ECHO OFF
for /f "usebackq tokens=*" %%a in (`dir /b /a:d`) do (
pushd %%a
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION 
for /f "delims=" %%b in ('dir /b "*.E01" "*.L01" "*.AD1" 2^>nul') do (
SET EVIDENCE_STR=!EVIDENCE_STR! /e:"%~dp0%%a\%%b"
)
IF DEFINED EVIDENCE_STR (
ECHO !EVIDENCE_STR!
) ELSE (
ECHO No evidence files located in: %%a 
)   
endlocal
SET EVIDENCE_STR=
popd
)
PAUSE
```

Comment: Depending upon your directory depth you could easily reach the 8192 character command line length limit of `cmd.exe` and if your command line requires full paths then there's no way to not provide it full paths! If you provide more information and the actual command, not some hidden, secret or generic example perhaps somebody could offer a reasonable working solution specific to it.

Comment: So what is stopping you from using the command modifiers with the `FOR` variable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why do you need to create 2 loops, each running a `dir` command to find files? Why not just do `for /R` loop? Here is an example:

```
@echo off
set "files=*.E01 *.L01 *.AD"
for /R %%a in (%files%) do echo %%a
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use "Sub"-Option: **/S** of the **DIR**-Command:

```
Dir /B /S C:\*.jpg
```

cause it is that equivalent to:

```
@echo off
 set "DirPath=C:\"
 set "files=*.jpg"
 for /R %DirPath% %%a in (%files%) do echo %%a
```

and so you should got the same result in each script.
The Problem: If you don't want any deep of SubDirectorys, you've to filter out these and so you may lose time - in both solutions.